# Using a Connection String with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I have a Web API project using Entity Framework using the default local database, how can I change it to use a connection string for a new database?

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

`Web config`: https://pastebin.com/rKaJ8p6V

Answer (score 2):

Here is a connection string example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxxDbContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:hostname,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxDb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And then, you can use it this way, where `xxxDbContext` is your EntityFramework `DbContext` class.

```
using (xxxDbContext db = new xxxDbContext("name=xxxDbContext"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention *why* the code is at it is: if the name of connection string *matches* the name of the context class, then there's no need in base constructor call - as in @MofidMoghimi's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `configuration` tag in `Web.Config` file, use `connectionStrings` tag like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="[Your Connection String Name]" connectionString="Server=.;initial catalog=[your Database name];integrated security=sspi" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

And your `DbContext` constructor class, use your connection string

```
public class DatabaseContext:DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext():base("[Your Connection String Name]")
    {

    }


}
```